# TinyMce replacing values in template

Tags: javascript, templates, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a question regarding the replacement of values inside tinymce templates.

I have the following code in my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Next, get a free TinyMCE Cloud API key!</textarea>
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
      plugins: "template",
      toolbar: "template",
      templates: [
        {title: 'Some title 2', description: 'Some desc 2', url: 'development.html'}
      ],
      template_replace_values: {
        username: "Jack Black",
        staffid: "991234"
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside my `development.html` I have this:

Preview Text

```
<!-- This will not be inserted -->
<div class="mceTmpl">
    <span class="username">This should be replaced?</span>
</div>
```

If I understand the tinymce documentation correctly, the text "This should be replaced?" should be replaced with Jack Black. From the tinymce documention on `template_replace_values`:

> This is an array of items that controls content replacement in the
>   inserted  templates. The array keys equal the classnames used in the
>   template. If a template element matches a classname in this array its
>   contents will be replaced by the array value. [TinyMce Docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/template/#template_replace_values)

This does not work and left me wondering how to use that feature. Would be glad for any example on how to get this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that the plugin actually does exactly what the documentation states.  I have created a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows how you can use what the documentation calls "snippets" to do what you need:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/QSfaab

I work for the makers of TinyMCE - I am going to follow up with our Engineering team to see if the documentation can be adjusted to make the use of this clearer.

Comment: Hmm, I see, thanks. What you posted is a "snippet" tho, theres no way to make it work with "templates" ? As in, have a seperate file where values are replaced in?

Comment: The template plugin allows you to store the original template code in a separate file - I did not do that in my fiddle to simplify things.  Snippets would still work regardless of how the template plugin loads the template code.  The class replacement that is mentioned in the documentation is actually no longer part of that plugin.  We are going to correct the documentation to remove that incorrect information.

Comment: @Michael Fromin can you check this pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747796/how-to-change-link-color-on-tinymce-once-linked-added